# Magento: How to create an instance of a block class?

Tags: block, magento-1.4

In the core of Magento there is the *app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options.php* class for example.

How would I create an instance of that? I tried

```
Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options');
```

and it worked, but since this is not a Model class, but a Block class it seems wrong to create it that way. Whats the alternative to that?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just use new Operator

```
$block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options();
```

as the classes will be autoloaded when you request them !

Comment: Don't do that. What if I want to rewrite that block?! See @PhilB's reply. **That's** how you should do it.

Answer (score 17):

Use the createBlock method:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_options')
```

Comment: While this method works, it's best to create blocks in xml files and display them in template files using the getChildHtml() method. It's more flexible this way - allows replacing blocks when needed or removing them entirely in other xml files.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use createBlock on the Layout, but blocks don't all have a getLayout method.

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_grid');
```

This is a better technique to "new My_Module_Block_Name" following as it allows for block rewrites in the config.

Defining the blocks in XML, as @Bartosz Górski suggests above, is preferable though it's not possible to directly define diverse dynamic content. Magento has a good solution for this in the  Cart's item rendering system - it creates the blocks dynamically but loads their configuration from XML before rendering.